# How to set locale settings with CasperJs?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to emulate that user changes to different languages in the browser. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maerlyn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25746369) works well if subsequent requests (AJAX) are not language dependent. If you want that all requests accept a specific language you can set the [`customHeaders`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/custom-headers.html) property that PhantomJS provides under the hood. For example before even starting:

```
casper.page.customHeaders = {
    'Accept-Language': 'hu'
};
```

Even AJAX requests use those headers, I checked with wireshark and [this](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/716fa7090745725178a5) script.

Answer (score 2):

You can set arbitrary headers using the second parameter of [`open()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#open):

```
casper.open('http://example.com', {
    headers: {
        'Accept-Language': 'hu'
    }
});
```

I suspect the same works with `thenOpen()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
casper.on('started', function () {
    this.page.customHeaders = { 'Accept-Language': 'en-US' }
});
```